# XML::LibXML.findvalue returns concatenated results for multiple nodes with same tag

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file that contains multiple nodes with the same tag. `findvalue()` returns all of the values concatenated. What is a good way to return just one value?

Example:

```
my $playlists = "<playlists> \
    <dict> \
        <key>Name</key><string>Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans</string> \
        <key>Description</key><string>Live album</string> \
        <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>67312</integer> \
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>F28F195257143396</string> \
        <key>All Items</key><true/> \
        <key>Playlist Items</key> \
    </dict> \
</playlists>";

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $playlists);
foreach my $playlist ($dom->findnodes('/playlists/dict')){
    say "Playlist: " , $playlist->findvalue('./string');
}
```

Returns:

```
Playlist: Yes - Tales From Topographic OceansLive albumF28F195257143396
```

I just want the first result. Is there a way to iterate through these results or access the results as an array?

thanks

Comment: You've already asked this question, and it was already answered. Your queries are all wrong because you're asking for the `string` children of `dict`, not just the one after the `key` with text `Name`. See the answer to your earlier question for the correct path.

Comment: Re "*access the results as an array?*", Even though it involves a lot of work, and even though it went far beyond what you asked in your earlier question, this was also provided in my answer to your earlier question. See the footnote. It provides code to convert the XML in a nice data structure, which includes providing the playlist as a hash.

Comment: thank you. I wasn't sure if I presented the first post correctly. Yes, a waste of space and people's time. sorry

Answer (score -1):

I am not expert using modules in the Markup languages however I have a `key` to help you on your progress.

```
use XML::LibXML;
use feature qw(say);

my $playlists = "<playlists> \
    <dict> \
    <key>Name</key><string>Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans</string> \
    <key>Description</key><string>Live album</string> \
    <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>67312</integer> \
    <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>F28F195257143396</string> \
    <key>All Items</key><true/> \
    <key>Playlist Items</key> \
    </dict> \
</playlists>";

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $playlists);
foreach my $news ($dom->findnodes('/playlists/dict/key[position()=1]'))
{
    say "Playlist: ", $news, "\t", $news->findvalue('/playlists/dict/string[position()=1]');
}
```

You can go through the below sites and refer `position`, `preceding`, `following` commands on `XML::LibXML` will helpful for your further notes. Thanks.

```
>OUTPUT:
Playlist: <key>Name</key>       Yes - Tales From Topographic Oceans
```

Search engine had several websites to [refer](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/xpath.html), this is just I got it immediate.

Comment: There are two Major problems with this solution. 1) Your solution doesn't work if there are more than one `/playlists/dict`, an incorrect assumption based on the sample XML the OP gave in their previous question. The second XPath should be relative, not absolute.

Comment: 2) Your solution assumes the elements of a dictionary are ordered, but it's common for dictionaries to be unordered. And even if they are ordered, you assume there's a guarantee that the Name will be first. While more likely, there's nothing to back that assumption. You should get the value associated with the correct `key`  (i.e. the one following the correct key); not the first `string`. For that, you need `key[text()="Name"]/following-sibling::*[position()=1]`

Comment: @ikegami: Accepted. Most of the time I wouldn't answered these type of xml related questions. Since I do not know how to use xml modules. Just I got in the web, that's why I answered.